# Xcode 6 auto layout Buttons overlap each other

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I'm having a problem with auto layout in XCode 6.  I have 2 buttons in a view - the buttons overlap each other.  I've tried spacing them out further from each other in storyboard, I've also tried resetting onstraints on them, various combinations of constraints on them, and various constraints on the View Controller.  None of this seems to work, they always seem to overlap each other, when I want to have at least some space between horizontally.

I'm attaching a screenshot for reference.  Thanks for any advice on this.

[image]

Comment: What I would do is set a minimum constraint between then. Some distance (like 8). Then Set a super high priority on it (higher than any other constraint). Then they will never ever overlap, no matter what.

Comment: Hi, if my answer helped you could you mark it accepted, or I'm always interested in hearing if you found another solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in AutoLayout to set an *even* number of items to be equally spaced from the center of the superview. You will need to create a clear placeholder view between them, center it in the superview (and give it constraint-based height width), then set each button to be horizontally offset from that.